# Doctrine typed query results IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: php, intellij-idea, doctrine-orm, typing

Is it possible to add type information to Doctrine query results? I'm following the [doctrine tutorial](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/tutorials/getting-started.html).

```
<?php
// show_bug.php <id>
require_once "bootstrap.php";

$theBugId = $argv[1];

$bug = $entityManager->find("Bug", $theBugId);

echo "Bug: ".$bug->getDescription()."\n";
echo "Engineer: ".$bug->getEngineer()->getName()."\n";
```

In this example `$bug` is typed `null|object` according to my IDE (IntelliJ IDEA). Because of this there is no auto-completion available on parameters and functions of a `Bug` object. Is it possible to enable typing to these objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this PHPDoc block to tell to your ide which kind of variable is:

```
/** @var ClassName $object */
```

Comment: This does work! Is this the only solution? I was hoping for something more intelligent from the IDE.

Comment: Is the solution for your problem, I don't know if there is another way but I think no. Because It need to understand which kind of class is your variable because you aren't done a new ClassName() for example